# Access previous element item in angularjs filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When creating a filter in angularjs how do I access the previous item in the array?
i.e I want to compare the current element to the previous one

Comment: Show us your code please.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to figure out exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I think if you're using an ng-repeat you can do this:

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="element in elements">
    <div>{{ element | myFilter:elements:$index</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
.filter("myFilter", function(){
    return function(input, elements, index){

        if(index > 0){
            var previousElement = elements[index - 1]
        }

        return input;
    }
});
```

**Edit**

Ok now that you've specified what you're trying to do, you can use a filter in a different way to instead remove the duplicate dates.

Here's the filter:

```
.filter("uniqueDates", function(){
    return function(input){
      var returnInput = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < input.length; x++){
            if(returnInput.indexOf(input[x]) === -1){
                returnInput.push(input[x]);
            }
        }

      return returnInput;  
    };
})
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the html and everything all wired up that you can extrapolate from: http://jsfiddle.net/nE9EE/

Comment: using ng-repeat, I have an array of dates and only want to show each unique date, not every date

Comment: Seems like you filter just needs to [remove duplicate entries from the array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/586621).

Comment: your answer just gives me an undefined for index